# Using :limit in to_json Statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently struggeling with the to_json Helper inside Rails

I want to include the first 5 curve_measurements.
This is what my code is looking at the moment :

```
Sector.first.curves.to_json(:include => {:curve_measurements => {:except => [:created_at,:updated_at,:curve_id],:limit => 5}, :curvetype =>{}})
```

The Result includes all curve_measurment values and not just the first 5. 
So it seems that the :limit parameter does not affect my query.

How is it possible to just include 5 or 10 curve_measurements instead of all ?

Comment: Not sure but maybe `Sector.first.curves.limit(5).to_json(...)`?

Comment: Does not work, this will just limit the number of curves and not the measurements :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two alternatives:

Just create a method in `Curve` called `five_cms` like:

```
def five_cms; curve_measurements.limit(5); end
```

And then do:

```
Sector.first.curves.to_json({
  :include => {
    :five_cms => {
      :except => [:created_at,:updated_at,:curve_id],
    },
    :curvetype => {}
  }
})
```

Or add a limit to your association in `Curve`. In Rails 4, you could do it like:

```
has_many :five_cms, lambda { limit(5) }, class_name: 'CurveMeasurement'
```

In Rails 3 and earlier I think it's:

```
has_many :five_cms, limit: 5, class_name: 'CurveMeasurement'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json), it doesn't appear that `to_json` can take a `limit` param, so it's just being ignored. I believe `to_json` is semi-deprecated in favor of `as_json`, however, so you might try that instead: [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

Comment: `as_json` is Rails-only helper, where `to_json` is commonly provided by many Ruby classes by default. `as_json` has some nice options for web development, which is why it’s been done like that, I guess.